# Is it legal or child-labor for a private pre-school to ask preschoolers to wash dishes without compensation?

Tags: united-states, labor-law, children, child-abuse

Is it legal for a private pre-school to ask preschoolers to take-turns to wash everyone's lunch dishes in the kitchen on behalf of all other students? It was a rotational. It was not singling out a specific person. I think two people worked on it cooperatively.

I know a friend in the United States whose pre-school asked them to wash dishes one-day when they were four-years-old. Then the pre-school shutdown some subsequent days later because the nuns ran out of funding.

Is this child-labor/abuse?

Comment: What dishes? What they just used for snack? Or dishes from the kitchen? Two very different things...

Comment: from the Kitchen inside the kitchen@JonCuster

Comment: also child labor:  cleaning chalk erasers

Comment: Hmmmm.... I'd be more concerned about safety dealing with large pots and pans or knives... Given the school has shut down for lack of funds, what is the point in pursuing this?

Comment: maybe the school was shutdown because someone sued the school for asking their children to wash dishes rather than hiring staff?@JonCuster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably permitted on the theory that socializing children to do household type chores serves a reasonable educational purpose.

If the dishes being washed were from a restaurant unrelated to the pre-school, on the other hand, this would probably be prohibited child labor.

Comment: it might also hinge on the amount: having 2 kids wash the dishes of 20 might be ok, while 2 of 200 might be excessive.

Comment: @Trish Without a doubt, specific factual details matter.